# Reload a div by using the same div

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, greasemonkey, reload

i want to write a greasemonkey script that reloads every 10 sec. the same div of the same page. But i only know how to load a complete page into a div :(
of course my script below does'nt work...

```
function Ajax(){
var xmlHttp;
    try{    
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }catch (e){
        try{
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }catch (e){
            try{
                xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }catch (e){
                alert("No AJAX!?");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        document.getElementById('ReloadDIV').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
        setTimeout('Ajax()',10000);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET","#ReloadDIV",true);
    xmlHttp.send(null); 
}
window.onload=function(){
    setTimeout('Ajax()',10000);
}


<div id="ReloadDIV">Text Text</div>
```

Comment: `xmlHttp.open("GET","#ReloadDIV",true);` - You're fetching the URL `#ReloadDIV`, which is rather a selector for an element. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: i know that i have to place an url, but instead the url i want to use the div (which is checked every 10sec. to update itself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one problem is the **onreadystatechage** which should be:

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById('ReloadDIV').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
    setTimeout('Ajax()',10000);
    }
    }
```

**readyState = 4** means request is finished and response is ready and the **status = 200** is an OK response from the server

Answer (score 0):

"I want to write a greasemonkey script that reloads every 10 sec. the same div of the same page."

This cannot be done like your trying to do it xmlHttp.open only works with valid urls. What you probably would want to do is call the page, scrape it and grab the elements you want and then replace the div.